# Ruby call constructor with random parameters count

Tags: ruby

I have some classes like

```
class Demo1 < Struct.new(:text, :text2) 
end
class Demo2 < Struct.new(:text, :text2, :text3) 
end
```

How can I call constructor of each class if I only have name and hash of parameters
I need to write method like this,
but this is wrong becasue after send(:new,args)  Struct will contain :text which equal to args

```
 def call_demo_object(demo_name, args={})
          demo_name.to_s.constantize.send(:new,args) 
  end
```

The mian  problem is calling constructor with random parameters from hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible variant:

```
def call_demo_object(demo_name, args={})
  obj = demo_name.new
  obj.members.each do |member|
    obj[member] = args[member]
  end
  obj
end
```

It's pros:

- `args` can be in any order
- only availible structure members will be assigned

Answer (score 3):

variant one:

```
def call_demo_object(demo_name, args={})
  z = [':new']
  args.keys.each do |key|
    z.push "args[:"+key.to_s+"]"
  end
  eval('demo_name.to_s.constantize.send(' + z.join(', ') +')' )
end
```

variant two:

```
def call_demo_object(demo_name, args={})
  a = demo_name.to_s.constantize.send(:new)
    args.each do |key, value|
      a[key] = value if a.members.include?(key)
    end
  a
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of things wrong:

Not sure if your classes really look like that, but you'll need `end` at the end of them, otherwise you'll get syntax errors.

Also, `constantize` is not a method on strings in Ruby, it's something Rails defines. So you'll need to use

```
Kernel.const_get(demo_name.to_s)
```

to get the same functionality.

As pointed out in the comments I neglected to mention how to expand the parameters.

To do that you'll need to use what's called the "splat operator"

```
Kernel.const_get(demo_name.to_s).send(:new,*args) #notice the * in front of args
```

That will expand args out.

However, when args is a hash, say `{:text=>"hello", :text2=>"hello2"}`, it will expand it out to an array with 2 elements where each element is an array with they key in the first position and key in the second position.

Instead, if you pass an array in as `args` with the objects in order, you will get what you're looking for.

I think if you're going for what amounts to named parameters, you might have to try another route, but I don't know that for sure.

To go with optional or named parameters, you might look at how Rails does it: use a hash for the parameter, then pass in a hash with the keys. You can then keep a valid list of keys and check the passed-in hash and either reject them or raise an error.

Comment: thanks , but qustion is about sending parameters, but not about constructor calling

Comment: Kernel.const_get(demo_name.to_s) - is better of course
but solution is still needed

Comment: thanks for updating your answer, if I cant find solution with hash I would use arrays instead

Comment: named parameters much more flexibly and easy to use... maybe there are different approach for using named parameters ?